# Problem with jagged/pixellated prints

Tags: print-production, pixelation, digital-printing, laser

I'm at my wit's end so I thought I'd throw my question out there!
I recently bought a new laser printer, a monochrome Samsung xpress M2835DW. Set it up all proper and everything.

I wanted to use it to print b&w images from Photoshop but I haven't managed to get one single print right so far. The lines all appear pixellated/jagged/horrible, as if I were trying to print some low resolution file that I enlarged too much.

Tried to take pictures:

[image]

[image]

The pics tend to make the effect more subdued but in real life it's horrid.

I'm trying to print images and texts that I drew at 400dpi. My printer is supposed to have two settings: normal resolution (600dpi) and high (1200). I haven't had any success with any of the settings.

Any clue where the problem comes from? You'd be life savers ! :(

Comment: You said "that I drew at 400dpi." - but that tells us nothing about the quality of the image. What is the size of the images in pixels please? And what size are you trying to print the image?  Of course I'm not discounting the fact the printer could be faulty, and therefore you'll need to contact Samsung probably.

Comment: Aw sorry ! The file is A4 in size (4677 x 3307 px) and I'm trying to print at A4. I should add that if I try to print it size A5 for instance, the pixellated effect is even worse.

Comment: I think then this is a case of a possible tech support question for Samsung . . .

Comment: "Drew" *how*? Are these vector paths/shapes? Or raster layers? That printer does **not** support Postscript Level 3 printing, so that *may* be the issue based on image construction. If you save the file as a PDF, then print the PDF from Reader or Acrobat, are prints better?

Comment: I drew them by hand on my cintiq in Photoshop so these are raster layers. I tried saving the file as PDF and printing it from Reader but the issue persists. Could you explain to me what Postscript is please ?

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain. This printer is the worst electronic item I have ever owned.

I've been in touch with HP support about this for over a week now. The only answers they give me is:

"We discussed the case with L2 and they informed us that it is a product limitation. The printer that you have is a very basic printer and might not be able to print pictures and graphics converted from high resolution pictures. "

"We have checked the case with our Level 2, the feature is limited on the printer."

"I have reviewed the case with our support team, who after trouble shooting with you and reviewing the screen shoots you have provided, consider the printer is performing to specification and that there is no fault with it. This printer is one of our lowest priced Laser printers, designed to provide just a basic printing function and we believe the level of print quality that you are looking for is not possible with this model of printer."

Which is a complete joke since the printer can print VECTOR files perfectly so it is indeed CAPABLE. Plus pixelated and jagged printouts of simple black lines is not 600dpi.

Throw this garbage out. I have ordered a new printer. I've spent months on this pathetic excuse of a printer and I am not doing it anymore. Will send it back and not let it go.

The specification isn't correct then. 
It is advertised as this:

*"Even complex images and small text are delivered in fine, detailed prints, thanks to high-resolution print quality up to 4800 x 600 dpi effective." 
"Enjoy clearer text and more vivid images thanks to edge enhancement, which gives them a far more polished and well-defined edge."

Give a good impression with great print quality
Now impressive professional-quality prints are possible for everyone. Your Samsung Xpress M2825DW Series delivers sharp, clear prints that are sure to make a big impact. Thanks to its 4800 x 600 dpi effective resolution and Rendering Engine for Clean Page (ReCP) technology, you can enjoy higher perfor-mance and quality without the need for a bulky larger printer. What's more, quality-boosting features give you more detail, smoother images and clearer text."

Makes you laugh doesn't it?

DO NOT BUY THIS PRINTER. SAVE YOURSELF THE TROUBLE.